# React Native: useState inside of useEffect does not update the state variable

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Ok so I feel like I am just missing something very obvious here and I have been trying to work through it on my own for a couple hours now to no avail. I'm creating an app with React Native and in my main App.js file I am doing this (for brevity's sake assume that I am requiring in all that is necessary) --

```
    const App = () => {
    let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
      DoHyeon_400Regular,
    });
    
    const [state, setState] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
      async function test(){
        let response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
          setState(json)
          console.log(state)
        })
      }
      test()
    }, [])
    return(
      <View>
        // some component(s)
      </View>      
    )
   }
```

From what I have read in the docs and a few other SO posts I have checked I do not see why this does not work. Version of React is > 16.8 so that should not be the issue. If I log out json var it displays the proper response from the API call.

Comment: And where do you use `state`?

Comment: Have you tried removing the json() ->> json. Then tried

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`state` is a local const. It will never change, and that's not what `setState` is trying to do. Instead, calling setState tells react to rerender the component. When that rerender occurs, a new local variable is created with the new value.

So everything's working, except that your console.log is in a spot where it's not particularly useful. If you want to see that the component has rerendered with the new value, move the log statement to the body of the component.

```
const [state, setState] = useState({});
console.log("rendering with", state);

useEffect(() => {
  async function test(){
    let response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
    let json = await response.json();
    setState(json);
  }
  test()
}, [])
```

Comment: Thanks man, I had a feeling that I was doing something stupid :)

Answer (score 1):

`setState` is not synchronous. If you immediately log the state, you will not notice the update.
Also, if you use the `await` keyword, you don’t have to use `then` anymore.