# State variable does not change inside useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In the following useEffect, data is fetched and is logged successfully:

```
const [allBooks, setAllBooks] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
  axios.get('/all_books').then(res => {
  setAllBooks(res.data);
  console.log(res.data)
  //console.log(allBooks)
   
  }).catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
  });
  
  }, []);
//...
return(
{allBooks.length > 0 ? (
  <div className="books__directory">
  <ul>
  {allBooks.map(book => (
  <li key={book.id}>
  <h3>{book.title}</h3>
  <h3>{book.language}</h3>
  <h3>{book.category}</h3>
  </li>
  ))}
  </ul>
  </div>
  ) : (
  <Spinner animation='border'/>
  )});
```

However, when I try the following log : `console.log(allBooks)`, it logs an empty object. Which means the state variable is not updated. The jsx component always displays the spinner. I tried the method suggested here [React Native: useState inside of useEffect does not update the state variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63098374/react-native-usestate-inside-of-useeffect-does-not-update-the-state-variable) but the issue still persists. This is how the other alternative I used inside useEffect:

```
async function fetchData() {
    let response = await axios.get(`/all_books`)
    let data = response.data
    setAllBooks(data)
    console.log(allBooks)
  }
  fetchData()
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have `reactjs` tag and are referencing to React Native, so which are you using?

Comment: And you don't have a context of where are you: "*`console.log(allBooks)`, it logs an empty object. Which means the state variable is not updated.*" - I'm guessing you are using it inside the `.then` method which is the expected behavior because by the time you are console.logging the state - the state is not updated *yet* and it shows the *current state* and you can read more at [rendering-takes-a-snapshot-in-time](https://react.dev/learn/state-as-a-snapshot#rendering-takes-a-snapshot-in-time)

Comment: @Aleksandar
 Thank you for you response. I'm using reactjs and not react native. And even when I tried to update it with an async function (without the ```.then``` method, it is still not updated

Comment: Where are you calling `console.log(allBooks)`? Please include that in your code samples for more context. When there are asynchronous interactions, it’s important to know exactly where something is called.

Comment: @LawrenceWebDev, I edited the code. In the two cases it logs an empty array

Comment: Does your line `console.log(res.data)` print out a populated array?

Answer (score 1):

When I try to console.log a temp array, I can see the values on the console.
I just write the console.log outside the useEffect hook, just before the return. Here, you may find the [demo in this link.](https://codesandbox.io/s/useeffect-demo-iorcqr)

Another solution might be using async function to get your data. But whatever you do, the state setter functions are sync functions, you can not await them and you can not write a logic relying on awaiting state setters.

Here is the async logic for useEffect,

```
const [allBooks, setAllBooks] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const getData = async() => {
    await axios.get('/all_books').then(res => {
    setAllBooks(res.data);
    }).catch(error => {
   console.log(error);
    });
 }
 getData();

 }, []);

console.log(allBooks)
```

Answer (score 1):

`setAllBooks` itself is asynchronous, and will update `allBooks` whenever. Just add some logic to only do stuff if `allBooks` is not empty.

Like you can have an effect like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (allBooks.length) {
    console.log(allBooks);
  }
}, [allBooks]);
```

Or if you just put your `console.log` outside of your current `useEffect` you should see that it gets run multiple times, printing out the data eventually.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I edited the code to show the issue wrt the jsx component. Even with the solution you proposed this component only displays the spinner and does not change it